# springroo install from scratch

Tags: spring-roo

I want to know where does springroo console saves its state? I want to have a clean springroo installation, I tried to delete all from installation directory and unpack there downloaded archive, but that didn't help, moreover springroo lost some its preinstalled bundles

```
roo> download accept Command 'download accept' not found 
(for assistance press TAB or type "hint" the n hit ENTER)
Located add-on that may offer this command
1 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.1 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 1.1.1.RELEASE Provides POM configuration inheritence for standard Roo...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search res
ult
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search r
esult, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific
add-on version
```

and if I try to execute

```
addon install id --searchResultId 01
```

springroo console firstly downloads something and then throws exceptions

```
roo> addon install id --searchResultId 01
Target resource(s):
-------------------
Spring Roo - User Agent Analysis (UAA) Integration (1.1.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

Deploying...done.

[Thread-2] [org.apache.felix.bundlerepository [2]] Resolver: Update error - Spri
ng Roo - User Agent Analysis (UAA) Integration
           java.lang.NullPointerException
               at org.springframework.roo.felix.HttpPgpUrlStreamHandlerServiceIm
pl.openConnection(HttpPgpUrlStreamHandlerServiceImpl.java:75)
           at org.apache.felix.framework.URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.openC
onnection(URLHandlersStreamHandlerProxy.java:271)
           at java.net.URL.openConnection(Unknown Source)
           at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.FileUtil.openURL(FileUt
il.java:196)
           at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ResolverImpl.deploy(Res
olverImpl.java:563)
           at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl._deploy(
ObrCommandImpl.java:395)
           at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl.deploy(O
brCommandImpl.java:333)
           at org.apache.felix.bundlerepository.impl.ObrCommandImpl.execute(
ObrCommandImpl.java:119)
           at org.apache.felix.shell.impl.Activator$ShellServiceImpl.execute
Command(Activator.java:286)
           at org.springframework.roo.felix.FelixDelegator.perform(FelixDele
gator.java:218)
           at org.springframework.roo.felix.FelixDelegator.obrStart(FelixDel
egator.java:207)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source
)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at org.springframework.roo.support.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMet
hod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedEx
ecutionStrategy$1.callback(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:49)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProces
sManager.doTransactionally(DefaultProcessManager.java:180)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProces
sManager.execute(DefaultProcessManager.java:143)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedEx
ecutionStrategy.execute(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:47)
           at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommand(Abs
tractShell.java:165)
           at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotOperati
onsImpl.installOrUpgradeAddOn(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:207)
           at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotOperati
onsImpl.installAddon(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:184)
           at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotOperati
onsImpl.installAddOn(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:179)
           at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnCommands.inst
allId(AddOnCommands.java:69)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source
)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
           at org.springframework.roo.support.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMet
hod(ReflectionUtils.java:191)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedEx
ecutionStrategy$1.callback(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:49)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProces
sManager.doTransactionally(DefaultProcessManager.java:180)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.internal.DefaultProces
sManager.execute(DefaultProcessManager.java:143)
           at org.springframework.roo.process.manager.ProcessManagerHostedEx
ecutionStrategy.execute(ProcessManagerHostedExecutionStrategy.java:47)
           at org.springframework.roo.shell.AbstractShell.executeCommand(Abs
tractShell.java:165)
           at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.promptLoop(JLin
eShell.java:358)
           at org.springframework.roo.shell.jline.JLineShell.run(JLineShell.
java:132)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
NullPointerException at org.springframework.roo.addon.roobot.client.AddOnRooBotO
perationsImpl.installOrUpgradeAddOn(AddOnRooBotOperationsImpl.java:210)
```

Answer (score 0):

You've asked a few questions here, so I'll take them one by one:

- "download accept Command 'download accept' not found" - the correct command is "download accept terms of use", which the shell will auto complete for you if you type "dow[tab]a[tab]".
- "I tried to delete all from installation directory and unpack there downloaded archive, but that didn't help" - the installation directory is the only place that Spring Roo (well, 1.1.5 anyway) stores anything, apart from some usage information saved via the Java Preferences API; for all practical purposes, blowing away Roo's home directory and re-installing should give you a clean start.
- java.lang.NullPointerException - I can't diagnose this without more information, but if you can replicate it in the [latest release](http://www.springsource.com/download/community), please [log a ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/secure/CreateIssue!default.jspa) with enough information for us to replicate it.

Apart from JIRA, you can also raise issues via the [forum](http://forum.springsource.org/forumdisplay.php?67-Roo), which we check regularly (unlike here on SO).

Answer (score 0):

**Roo cache directory**

*My best bet is that if you want to reset your Roo installation, you have to remove the Roo `cache` directory.*

Let me explain: I installed [STS](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) 2.8.1, which comes bundled with Roo 1.5.1.RELEASE and then, after installing, I created a local Git repository of the installation.

After running Roo once, it created the following cache, as can be seen from the Git status:

```
opyate:springsource git:(master*) $ git status                                                       
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/cache/
```

---

**Other interesting observations**

I ran the following commands on a fresh install of Roo 1.5.1.RELEASE:

```
development mode
download accept terms of use
pgp automatic trust
addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.mongo
```

...after which I also get a `NullPointerException` in the Roo process manager, and I ended up with the following extra bundles in the cache:

```
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.dod-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
obr://org.springframework.roo.addon.layers.repository.mongo/-1322818602247
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.addon.propfiles-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.classpath-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.file.monitor-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.file.undo-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.process.manager-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.support-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.support.osgi-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.metadata-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
```

...i.e. a whole lot of Roo cruft (that came with the installation) and one new Mongo OSGi package.

The `exit` command then hangs. `Ctrl-C` gets me out, but when I start Roo again, the fun starts. I get reams and reams of this:

```
ERROR: Error starting file:/Users/opyate/Applications/springsource/spring-roo-1.1.5.RELEASE/bundle/org.springframework.roo.project-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
...OSGi errors omitted for brevity's sake...
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3409)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1719)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1148)
at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

...and no Roo prompt. Removing the cache directory makes it work again, although I did not have time to pinpoint exactly which bundles in the cache caused the issue.